# string concat for a title forename surname combination in sql using isnull to check values

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

I have the following line of code in my select statement:

```
CONCAT(ISNULL([Customer].[Title]+' ',''),ISNULL([Customer].[Forename]+' ',''),ISNULL([Customer].[Surname],''))  AS [Customer Name],
```

This works as expected when all fields are completed but sometimes this is not the case and the alignment of the data in my select statement is not how i expected

```
Title  Surname
 Forename Surname
 Forename Surname
 Forename Surname
 Forename Surname
Title Forename Surname 
 Forename Surname
Title  Surname
 Forename Surname
 Forename Surname
 Forename1 Forename2 Surname
```

How can I concat the string properly so that the spaces are only added if the value is not null so if there is no title the first character is not trailing white space etc

notice when only a title and surname are given there are 2 spaces between and when no title is given a white space is shown at the start of the name string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like a lot of your blanks are actually the empty string, rather than NULL. You could do try wrapping your columns in NULLIF(Col,''), like this:

```
CONCAT(ISNULL(NULLIF([Customer].[Title],'')+' ',''),ISNULL(NULLIF([Customer].[Forename],'')+' ',''),ISNULL([Customer].[Surname],''))  AS [Customer Name],
```

There's no need to do it on the surname, because you're not trying to put a space on the end.

Do you need the reason about why this works?

Edit: the reason why is because when you 'add' a space to an empty string, you get a space. But if you add a space to NULL, you get NULL. The ISNULL is catching this second case, but not the first. Forcing the empty string to be treated as NULL resolves it. You could do similar with LTRIM, to strip any leading spaces from each section of the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 
  when isnull(@field1,'') = ''then ''
  else @field1 + ' '
end +
case 
  when @field2 is null then ''  -- if you know fields will never be '' but not null
  else @field2 + ' '
end  +
```

you get the idea... might be a new fancier way to do it

Comment: The first version you posted doesn't solve it. The later edit is an improvement, so I removed the downvote.